# How to get file's path created by this code?

Tags: vb.net, file, path, save

I'm using this code to save files in my app

```
 Dim filePath = String.Format("image{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.png", DateTime.Now)
    PictureBox1.Image.Save(IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), (filePath)))
```

So now I have a textbox1 and I want to show the path of last saved image in it 
how?

Regards,,,,

Comment: Presumably, `TextBox1.Text = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), filePath)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done in the past is generate the path in one step and then use the generated variable to do the saving and to display.

So instead of:

```
Dim filePath = String.Format("image{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.png", DateTime.Now)
PictureBox1.Image.Save(IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), (filePath)))
```

Try:

```
'Generate the Path
Dim path As String = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), String.Format("image{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.png", DateTime.Now))
'Save using the generated path
PictureBox1.Image.Save(path)
'Display the path
textbox1.Text = path
```

Comment: Great Mr. Mike_OBrien works , but how if I want to first create folder on desktop then to save image in that folder ?

Comment: @user206402 : You really ought to do some research on your own: https://www.google.com/search?q=VB.NET+create+folder

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all I've done it successfully `

```
  Dim filename As String = String.Format("image{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.png", DateTime.Now)
    Dim filePath1 = (IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), (filename)))
    Dim filePath2 = (IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), ("RMSS")))
    If IO.Directory.Exists(IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), (" RMSS"))) = True Then
        TextBox1.Text = filePath1
        TextBox2.Text = filePath2 & "\" & filename
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(filePath1)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, True)
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = filePath1
        TextBox2.Text = filePath2 & "\" & filename
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(filePath1)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, True)
    End If
```